# How do I add a LogoutEventStream trigger to a managed package?

Tags: apex, logout

I have added a LogoutEventStream trigger to my application. It works fine in a developer org, but I can't add it to my package. On the packaging org it appears in the Apex Triggers list like this:

[image: apex trigger row]

The detail shows I have adequate code coverage, so it's not that:

[image: trigger detail]

But when I try to add it to the package, it's not there:

[image: add trigger to package]

Obviously LogoutEventStream is a beta feature. Are we not allowed to add beta features to packages, or is there something I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [LogoutEventStream (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_logouteventstream.htm)

> As a beta feature, the LogoutEventStream object is a preview and isn’t
>   part of the “Services” under your master subscription agreement with
>   Salesforce. Use this feature at your sole discretion, and make your
>   purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available products
>   and features. Salesforce doesn’t guarantee general availability of
>   this feature within any particular time frame or at all, and we can
>   discontinue it at any time. This feature is for evaluation purposes
>   only, not for production use.

From docs, it looks like its not in Beta but in preview stage. Probably hence not allowed in packaging. On top of my head, when lightning components were in beta I was able to add them in my package, or even deploy in production.